# how to encode in Ant

Tags: encoding, ant

I have a test script:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project name="test" basedir=".">
   <echo encoding="UTF-8" file="test.txt">测试</echo>
   </project>
```

When I open test.txt. I only see "??"

Something more weird. The script run with no problem using Eclipse Ant tool, but it has problem with command line.

Both Eclipse and cmd are using the same Ant lib.

Comment: What encoding is your test script saved in, how are you opening `test.txt`?

Comment: script is saved in UTF-8. I was opening test.txt in UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Use this encoding :

```
 <echo encoding="UnicodeLittleUnmarked" file="test.txt">测试</echo>
```

And you will get the correct result in your file.

Comment: @performanceuser No actually it does work. From command line or from whatever other tool it's calling the ant script. With what editor do you try to view the generated file?

Comment: I tried to open using notepad++ and eclipse. I specifically changed encoding to utf-8

Comment: You should specifically set your eclipse to UTF-16 though :). I can see it correctly both in eclipse and visual studio.

Comment: What on earth is cmd? You try to display UTF-16 to cmd?

Comment: No I meant when I try to run the ant from cmd, the generated test.txt file doesn't display correctly. Whereas, when I run it in eclipse the generated test.txt file is good

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4152/discussion-between-performanceuser-and-faileddev)

Answer (score -1):

I found the reason.

Before running the Ant script, I need to set a system property:

```
Set ANT_OPTS=-D"file.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Then

```
<project name="test" basedir=".">
   <echo file="test.txt">测试</echo>
</project>
```

runs successfully even if there is no encoding in the echo.

Can anyone tells me why the original one doesn't work?

Comment: Questions do not belong in answers. If you need to update your question, please do so. Do not attempt to ask more questions in an answer.